# reference to undefined property obj.nodeType [jQuery error]

Tags: javascript, jquery

This error is beyond my understanding. I have written som script and am using jQuery and jQuery-ui. Now, when i open the site in firefox, firebug shows this error: "reference to undefined property obj.nodeType". And it points to this line in jquery.js file " **if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length ) {**" as the line causing it. Has somebody else faced this and tell me whats wring?

And the chrome dev tools show this for the same page:
**"event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. "**

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong way `if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length )` here just applying length is the key problem define it something like `length>0` or what you need. And you may be using return false, try using event.preventDefault() instead something like this:

```
$(selector).on('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //stuff goes here
}
```

---

```
if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length > 0 ){
```

Comment: i didn't get it. Please explain.

Comment: This one is really tricky as I don't even know which line to correct in the script.

Comment: yes i have used return false at places where i don't want an <a> tag to follow the link. So are you saying that i should replace it with  event.preventDefault()?

Comment: see also in my example event is passed as parameter in function

Comment: one more thing, event.preventDefault(); goes on top or bottom, i have used "return false" at the end in all the functions.

Comment: you can use anywhere but placing at first is best practice.

Comment: i replaced each "return false" with above. but, the error still remains.

Comment: did you change length that have been noticed.

Comment: that line is in the js file downloaded from its official release. Should i change it?

Comment: um, I'm confused now. just try once and check what errors appears and tell me

Comment: also i did change it just to check, it still shows error: "reference to undefined property obj.nodeType

Line 991"